# Should Stack Overflow have a programming skill test for asking questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, low-quality-posts, moderation

There was a huge increase in number of new Stack Overflow members from Asia in 2016-2017, especially from India, that doesn't have any or have very very little programming skills.

I have noticed this while reviewing questions. Before this increase happened I was enjoying reviewing questions. But these days I am only trying to guess and understand what these members are trying to ask. All the questions coming from these users are in very bad shape in terms of both English and programming aspects. It is mostly impossible to improve the question.

This situation wastes our time. What could we do to prevent this? My suggestion is Stack Overflow should have an online exam that measures users skills like companies use when they interview people online using sites like [Hacker Rank](https://www.hackerrank.com/).

Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Down vote, close vote, delete vote.  Eventually they will be quality banned if they do not improve.  That is about as good as you can get.

Comment: You should never go too personal talking about a country...

Comment: Don't we allow people to ask question before they learn how to ask a proper question Nathan?

Comment: We do.  The first question they ask, if bad, will generally show them how to ask a good one (by comments from people telling them how to use the site).

Comment: I have consider not to mention a specific country but they have a very large population. And having a very large population increasing the number of bad programmers. I hope our Indian firends doesn't take offence.

Comment: Downvotes on feature requests indicate disagreement - don't expect comments for all or even the majority of them as they're not necessary

Comment: No, no, no, no. If someone can formulate a good question that is on topic, they are welcome to post it, regardless of skill level. And an online 'test' is just as easily faked as ticking the checkbox on the first-time-askers information page, passing one proves nothing. Most of all, such a test would be hugely insulting to experienced developers that have a genuine new problem to solve.

Comment: The problem you describe is real - but an entrance test probably not the way to fix it.

Comment: There's no way you could formulate a test broad enough to account for the diversity of topics covered by this site. Even if you could, the same groups who are teaching their employees to create multiple accounts and vote in rings would just build a cheat sheet of answers. You'd drive away many potentially good askers and probably wouldn't solve the core problem.

Comment: On this topic : https://qz.com/977850/hyderabad-a-city-that-sends-the-most-software-engineers-to-the-us-has-the-worst-engineers-in-india/

Answer (score 19):

Gauging a person's skill level in programming is difficult, and time consuming.

Either the tests will be too difficult for a significant portion of the audience, such as budding and intermediate coders who haven't mastered 90% of the language, or it will be too easy, and serve as nothing more than a programming-oriented "Are you human?" captcha.

Assuming we could get a test "just right", what language would it be in? Java is certainly one of the most popular languages here, but if I'm here looking for Javascript help as a core JS developer, I'd be destroyed by any question related to even how to import a library.

If we were to expand the test to multiple subjects, then it becomes "Is your language significant enough to warrant a test?"

Or, someone could potentially just put all the answers online anyways. The amount of return from a test like this would absorb a significant amount of someone's time, for very little practical return.

I'd rather we get some bad apple questions that we can filter out than turn people away from the site entirely because of some arbitrarily created gate.

Comment: While I agree with the general drift of the answer, I have to ask this: "such as budding and intermediate coders" - are there ANY useful questions left that can be asked by this subgroup of programmers? My gut feeling is that any question asked by an inexperienced coder at this point would be a duplicate - at least in the more well-traveled tags.

Comment: @Arkadiy Even if it's a duplicate, it may be a duplicate that's hard to find or explain, or may be another problem with an identical solution. Even if it's a simple typographical error, we can still solve it and vote to close, thereby solving the problem for the asker. The goal is ultimately to help answer the question, and I don't see marking as dupe or closing as typo to be against this goal at all, nor should any new user who genuinely searched be ashamed of having their question closed.

Comment: "The goal is ultimately to help answer the question" - that's where we differ. The goal the way I understand it (can't find a more authoritative citation at the moment) is to have a complete set of commonly-useful, reusable answers to common, broadly-applicable questions from IT practitioners. The goal is not to replace your CS/IT professor. The goal is not to write a piece of code someone needs at school or at work. The "simple typographical error" is explicitly mentioned in Off Topic close reason. With my goal, it's hard for an inexperienced prgrmmr to offer a good question not yet answered.

Comment: 'Gauging a person's skill level in programming is difficult, and time consuming' and, going by the number of disputes between skilled and experienced developers/engineers on SO, impossible :)   Dare I mention tabs/spaces....

Comment: `Gauging a person's skill level in programming is difficult` fortunately, I think some basic questions way more simple than fizzbuzz would be pretty effective in weeding out the copy/paste warriors from legitimate learners.