# Stack Overflow needs an entrance exam

Tags: feature-request, questions, new-users, accounts

Every day, we see hundreds of questions asked that are of such low-quality one might wonder why Stack Overflow even allows to post it. We keep closing and downvoting them, but the problem doesn't end. New users arrive and the ones that get banned just create another account and repost the same question. We need something to stop it.

I propose that Stack Overflow implements an entrance exam. Every account must go through such an exam before being able to post any questions.

It could look something like this. We present a user with a question and they must select one of few options, e.g. "Answerable", "Duplicate", "Unclear", "Not about programming". When a user answers correctly 5 times they gain a privilege to ask questions. We could sample questions automatically like we do in audits or we could have moderators select a range of questions. If every moderator selects 5-15 questions it should be enough to present a viable challenge even to returning users.

This would have several benefits:

- Stop users who are in hurry.
- Show examples of good questions to new users. There is the tour, but it is useless at this task.
- Inform users what Stack Overflow is about. This is not a personal help assist. We are trying to collect a repository of questions and their answers.
- Deter voting fraud. It's too easy to create new accounts. This is not a primary reason, but I hope it will help in a fight with users who create multiple accounts to answer their own questions.
- Reduce the occurrence of the pattern: Ask, close, ban, recreate the account, ask again.
- Maybe even reduce spam.

This is just an idea, but I would like to hear everyone's opinion. Would you like to see something like this being implemented and if not, why?

Comment: A new user will be able to post an "answer" without sitting this exam?

Comment: I read "entrance exam" and thought _oh no, not that discussion again ..._, but the idea presented here, showing other questions to askers might be a good idea to give askers some way to reflect on the quality of their question

Comment: Yes, the goal is to prevent low-quality questions

Comment: "Maybe even reduce spam" - no, because spam is largely presented as answers, not as questions. It in general won't work towards what you think it will, because 375 questions (assuming 25 mods; couldn't be arsed to check how many there are) isn't a big enough sample. I can already think of several ways to bypass this, most of which rely on people sharing answers (which will happen). The only think this is gonna do is keep a lot of users away, but sufficiently motivated askers of trash are gonna do that in spite of this thin wall you're proposing

Comment: Entrance *exam* sounds a bit of an overkill to me - it will only alienate people further and will be used on social media as a prime example of us being "elitist". That said, this can actually replace the current useless tour (it would probably be a good idea to add an incentive of 100 initial rep, just like the association bonus, for new users who successfully complete it).

Comment: @OlegValter:  They're *already* calling us elitist, so...I see this similar to how [Concorde decided to *raise* ticket prices](https://theadaptivemarketer.com/2012/01/14/a-pricing-lesson-from-the-concorde/) because everyone already assumed it was expensive.  Phrased differently, we're already being called elitist, so doing yet another "elitist" thing to incur the ire of social media is a moot point.

Comment: @Makoto - I know... Just noting that by making this mandatory we would further solidify the perception for little to no gain (call that gut feeling, but something tells me this will be simply viewed as an entry bar to deal with as quickly as possible and forget). Although I do think that this could (and probably should) replace the current tour and be made more prominent with some additional incentive in place. This way we could educate those who are willing to be educated (which is, to my opinion, is the only thing we can do), so I am not against the idea overall.

Comment: Maybe it could be a small 5 question quiz or something... depending on the score the user will be able to post more or less. An entrance exam seems way too much.

Comment: Does this assume people posting poor questions do so because they don't know how to recognize a bad question? I'm pretty sure they do so because they don't care, they just want their problem solved.

Comment: It's not the numbingly low level of skill/experience so much as those low-quality questions are posted continually.  The same set, over, and over, and over again.  The users posting those questions don't care about tours, tests, searching or anything except getting an answer for the minimum of their own effort.  Searching for dupes is beneath them - the moronic, elitist, naive nerds can be easily conned into doing that grunt work, so why bother with it themselves?  If any of the geeks complain and they are easily blasted as 'toxic' on social media.

Comment: What about existing users? Would I need to sit the entrance exam if I ever wanted to ask a question? If not and we grandfather all existing users then would that mean that users with a history of low quality questions would not need to do the entrance exam?

Comment: @RobertLongson I would expect that existing users have to take this exam too, but we could automatically pass some users who asked 100 or more questions.

Comment: Yes, the barrier for entry ought to be raised (just a tiny, tiny, little bit), despite Atwood's famous original 2008 "no barrier for entry" declaration. It has already been raised once by requiring registration (that wasn't the case originally).

Comment: Most of the bad questions could be dealt with by a FAQ popup and a new close reason: 'OP too selfish to read and act on the FAQ'.  I can agree that an entrance exam is a non-starter, and so giga-dupes will continue to be posted.  We need an easier way to dump them.

Comment: I mean:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/67036613/758133. Sure enough, some cucumber has posted an answer and got +2 for it.  What is the point of bothering with curation at all?

Comment: What makes you think once implemented, googling "stack overflow entrance exam answers" wouldn't return results the next day?

Comment: @anon If they can Google the answers to the test then they can Google the solution to their problem.

Comment: We don't even agree what a good Question is. We have close/reopen and delete/undelete wars going on.

Comment: @Scratte True, but we mostly agree what a bad question is. Regardless, that is not the premise of this FR.

Comment: I disagree that it isn't the premise. The posts that are to be part of the "entrance exam" will have to be judged by un-experienced users, just like reviews and audits. How many meta posts do we have about wrong audits already? What if those chosen "entrance exams" are good Questions for some, but bad for others? I used to think that review training would be awesome for new users, but I don't think it is anymore. We're too divided on this.

Comment: @Dharman "If they can Google" - not sure that's true. Googling answers to exam questions does not take much expertise (if any at all). However, being able to correctly search for a solution for a given problem is a skill such people usually lack (knowing the appropriate terminology, for example). I'd say one does not entail the other at all.

Comment: I'd like to see *something*, but I don't think your suggestion is it. But if it's an opt-in thing, where the successful newbies get a badge and some bonus points, as Oleg suggested (although maybe 50 points rather than 100), it *might* be beneficial. It wouldn't get rid of the rubbish, but it could help the more sincere newbies to have a more positive on-boarding experience.

Comment: [Kinda related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367092/11573842)

Comment: The title would imply that you'd need an exam to access the site in general... but it's specifically about asking questions. "Exam"... egh. I don't like that name, it harkens back too much to the school days. Call it an interactive tutorial. People seem to love tutorials for whatever reason, a tutorial is probably part of the reason for the target audience of this FR needing Stack Overflow in the first place ;)

Comment: What if they fail?  Would we ban their IP address pertinently?

Comment: @Anonymous Or we could let them retake it.

Comment: This is kind of like the "guided question posting" experiment.

Comment: @Dharman yeah, retake it next year:)

Comment: Related: *[Create a separate, independent advanced Stack Overflow, focusing on being a knowledge library (but still part of the network)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390983)*

Comment: It doesn't need an entrance exam: it simply needs questions and answers from users with less than x ratio to not be immediately viewable/answerable by everyone. A visible barrier will simply be skipped; A hidden one cannot be skipped.

Comment: You want new users to be able to ascertain whether something is a duplicate? That seems a tall order, both in expectation and in implementation. Would there be an iframe on the page they could use to search? Or are they expected to open a new tab? Are we going to tell them from the get-go that it's probably more effective to go to google and search for their question with site:stackoverflow.com included? Etc.

Comment: @MartinJames That suggestion would be quite rude. Not sure what the example question you linked to is supposed to show, either; the question was closed *and deleted* within 24 hours of being posted.

Comment: I think the only way to make SO nice again (in the way that this Q wishes for) is to put the site (or at least the ability to ask questions) behind a paywall. A big fee isn't necessary, but restricting asking/membership behind a credit card number and a $1/month fee or something would eliminate almost all young students and drive-by users *who tend to ask bad questions*. It would prevent *good* younger users, yes, but I think it'd be a massively net gain in terms of question quality. Putting only the ask feature behind the paywall also has the benefit of not losing ad revenue from Google hits.

Comment: @TylerH and that's how the industry made a 180 and returned to the model that lead to SO creation in the first place :) Maybe that would help put the network out of its misery, though, and a new and improved project would arise from the ashes, so this might be a good idea

Comment: @OlegValter Eh, there's a big difference between sites like Experts Exchange, which puts a monetary barrier on seeing anything at all, and a monetary barrier only on asking. SO is also quite different from all the other various programming help sites out there, so even if it did institute a price on something, it wouldn't be 'the same as all the other stuff'. But sure, if innovation like this leads to a better site taking SO's place entirely, I'm all for that... capitalism and competition and all.

Comment: The problem is, the feedback from writing bad posts is currently the quickest path to truly learn what is and isn't accepted on Stack Overflow. New users often don't read the FAQs. I think there are better solutions to be had, such as an [interactive tutorial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411433/584676) exemplifying good and bad posts, and what makes them so.

Comment: @TylerH I was mostly joking around :) There is some truth to it, though as, if memory serves me right, one of the reasons for creating Stack Overflow was to deal away with the paywalled content so it would definitely feel like going back to the old times. However, the idea is not without merit, methinks - I've seen users popping up here and there with suggestions of "give back to the community" systems and, although I do not agree with their solutions, they seem to all converge in one sensible point - nudging question-askers to contribute something else than their lack of knowledge.

Comment: @OlegValter Yeah, I figured, and also yes, the paywalled content was a big problem... but it was paywalled answers. I can't foresee myself ever suggesting SO start paywalling answers (but never say never, I suppose?)

Comment: @TylerH heh, never say never :) Although that would be a truly grim day for the network. Anyways, as a friendly neighborhood communist, I don't like the idea of paywalls of any kind, but from time to time it does feel like it would at least partially compensate for all our wasted time and effort... Probably repurposing the post ban into something along the lines "post 5 well-received answers to continue" would be nice.

Comment: @OlegValter Yeah, I'd also be in favor of "try other non-monetary things like participation requirements before paywalling asking", of course.

Comment: So, would this entrance exam be applied to existing users? For example, a user with over 1,000,000 reputation points but has **yet to ask their first question**?

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes. A user with some experience should have no problem quickly passing it.

Comment: I don't think something like this should be mandatory, unless the user's most recent history of actions has been under dispute (lots of removed questions and answers, a pattern of ill-received posts but not removed, etc.) In that case providing such a quiz ([I prefer my suggestion of this though](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411433/584676)) would be a mandatory stage before continued poor contributions are met with the infamous ban on asking and/or answering questions.

Comment: If it were mandatory though, I would argue that established **and active** users shouldn't be made to take this except in the case their recent contributions have not been well received.

Comment: I suspect most of those have the *minimum effort attitude* and will never ever change their posts (other than trying to get them past the filter), not even after having posted meta questions.

Comment: Your suggestion is LIKELY in direct conflict with the company's goals. Do not forget SO is not a charity. It is a company whose main goal is to be profitable. If you limit the number of users, you are lowering the company's profits. In this case, I don't know how this is even up to contention here.

Comment: @Jellyboy You have to remember that most profits come from unregistered users. Users with reputation on the site are not shown ads and generate less profit for the company.

Comment: "*to post it*" = "*to post **them***"... (it/them = "*hundreds of questions*", = plural... => "them"...)

Comment: @Dharman I posted a similar suggestion but using a reward mechanism having a badge or bounty associated to the exam: [Badge or bounty to encourage questions and answers with good quality (pass an exam)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420495/badge-or-bounty-to-encourage-questions-and-answers-with-good-quality-pass-an-ex?noredirect=1#comment927809_420495), I think it could be an improvement to your initial proposal expressed in a more positive way. I posted it without knowing you posted something similar before. In case you would like to include in your initial proposal.

Answer (score 36):

The only thing that can stop the influx of users who don't really know what's going on with the site or how to use it is **for the company to realize, accept and own that this is something that they have to actually confront head-on as a matter of their *own* survival**, *not* us volunteers who have already gone through this cycle [for the umpteenth time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348922/1079354) trying to spitball ideas that we know, somewhere in the deepest darkest pits of our stomachs, have about a snowball's chance in Hell of actually working.

Case in point:  [they missed an opportunity to do this the last time they engaged with students/newer users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354804/175248).  Here's hoping they don't *next* time, if there can be a next time.

Answer (score 15):

Even though the idea tingles me, I don't think it's ever going to work.

**1. It makes the community look like elitists**, which will result in a massive amount of social network outrage, flames, civil wars, public hangings and the like. Even if the dust will settle eventually, I don't think the company will want that level of disruption.

**2. high-rep users can still ask bad questions**. The problem doesn't affect new accounts, specifically. Someone who can't be bothered to go through a tutorial before asking basic questions, will ask a slew of bad questions in the [X] tag the day they decide to learn X, without having to go through an "entrance exam".

**3. the company needs the metrics**, no need to pretend they don't, unless it becomes a non-profit based on donations from "club members". Then SO becomes just that, a private club, and also see point #1.

[warning: unpopular opinion]
**4. low-rep answerers need the bad questions**, because:

- 4a. not all bad questions are abysmal questions, and may be just answered
- 4b. not everyone has a 1000+ score answer from 2012 to what *today would be considered a bad question* about how to convert a number to a string in [programming language]
- 4c. you do want more people to gain enough rep to help you with the site curation. But if those people have to wait for the good questions, you'll also have to wait for that help. Yes, if there's fewer bad content, there's less curation work for you, but I don't think we can rely on this assumption. And no, it's not true that posting great answers by itself is enough to gain the rep, because reputation comes from visibility (in life, not just in here), not from quality alone. I could post a fantastic answer to a super obscure bug that affects two people this year and help them avoid spending the next 3 months debugging stuff and losing clients, and that would net me +35.

And lastly:
**5. if a question is really bad the OP likely won't get the answer they want**, simply because it can't be given. They will end up punished by their own lack of effort, and trust me, more often than not this will feel frustrating for them more than curating their questions feels frustrating for you. Unclear, poorly formatted, poorly researched questions make it impossible to get good answers by themselves, even if you don't close them.

So I don't think an entry exam is necessary at all. If you really want change something, please **remove the -1 rep cost when downvoting answers in the review queues**.

Comment: Counter argument to #1 is that leaving the floodgates open allows anything to continue to  get posted and more bad user experiences occur and they run off and rant and flame anyway.

Comment: @charlietfl that's the eternal clash between people who value quality and people who don't, or even, between people who value a community as a collective Good (capital G) and those who value it as a means to satisfy a personal need. I'm afraid this clash isn't bound to be solved here

Comment: Just FYI the goal is not to punish users. The goal is to stop the flow of poorly written questions. I understand what you are trying to say with point number 4 but you can still gain reputation by answering only selected questions, just much more slowly. I doubt that people amassing rep quickly have curation efforts in mind. I know it's the reason why I have 20k rep, but I see users with 100k and I have no idea what they use it for.

Comment: Agree but letting quality continue to slide is not in the company's best interest either. New customers  is not the only important metirc in a business model....conversion and churn rates are also important

Comment: @Dharman I'm one of those who, as you say, answers only selected questions (well, 90% of the time) *precisely* because I believe in the QA/QC effort you're talking about. But if you take a look at my profile, you can see that a significant portion of my answers do appear under less-than-stellar questions. So what's left if we take those away... but yeah, I know you know what I'm trying to say

Comment: "2. high-rep users can still ask bad questions" - definitely, especially if most of the rep came from answering easy questions. Reputation points prove diddly squat about what intentions the person leasing them has.

Answer (score 10):

I really don't like the way you worded it as an **entrance *exam***, but the idea of providing an **interactive *tutorial*** to new users I think is worthy for discussion. Something similar to what you have suggested but:

- Would be static, the same for everyone, possibly sourced from real questions or answers that have already been judged in the review queue.

  - The reason for a static experience is there is less chance a curated list of good/bad posts would be mistakenly judged incorrectly. Incorrect closures happen in the review queues periodically.
- If you get the answer wrong, it lets you try again until you get it right
- Whether you pick the right or wrong answer it explains why your choice is right or wrong.
- Would be short, two or three questions, five max. This shouldn't take more than five minutes to complete.
- It shows for your first question/answer, but perhaps a link or clickable button on the **Ask/Answer Question** forms would allow users to easily find the tutorial again if they skip it and find their posts are getting closed or deleted.
- Potentially offer a **Skip** button, though I'm on the fence whether that would deteriorate the value of this suggestion too much.
- Gamify the tutorial by providing **Score** (like +5) and/or a badge on first completion. This becomes a bit more valuable if the tutorial is made optional.
- A link to the tutorial would be provided in the banner on closed or deleted posts.
- The tutorial should include links to the **How to Ask/Answer** FAQ pages.

Calling it a ***mandatory exam*** I think would promote an elitist view of the community from the outside as others have mentioned. A ***tutorial*** solution would put the posting guidelines in front of new members in a way that doesn't teach them via a "trial by fire" (as in posting poor quality questions/answers), leading to unnecessary moderation in order for the poster to understand why their post was removed.

Yes, there are guidelines you can read but as is the case at many of our jobs, end users tend not to read the documentation in our line of work. This would be more engaging than "read the FAQ" and take less time to go through than reading and processing multiple FAQ pages which users aren't looking for; most of the time they have a question and just want an answer.

As many folks don't take the time to read these, they come to the site with a fundamental misunderstanding of how the community works. Their posts get downvoted or closed, the user gets **frustrated or feels unwelcome** and **may stop participating altogether**. We don't want this, **we *want*** **their participation**. A tutorial presented during their first question and answer posts wouldn't eliminate this entirely, but would be a more inclusive and engaging way to teach serious new users how to engage amicably with the community in a fun, interactive way.

Comment: As [previously stated](/q/406703/4642212#comment836426_406703), the downside of a static tutorial is that eventually it’s easy to Google “stackoverflow entrance tutorial answers” and effectively skip it. However, your suggestion sounds like you want it to be optional and your final paragraph does explain how this may be useful. I still have my doubts when considering the cost and benefits of this suggestion…

Comment: I think that is only a risk if it's an *exam*, a rite of entry so to speak, as presented in the original question. I feel **If you get the answer wrong, it lets you try again until you get it right** addresses this because it's not a quiz; you can't get it wrong and if you do, it would explain why it's not the correct answer and you simply try again. I'm proposing a guidance tool, not a competency gate.

Answer (score 5):

Surely it needs an exam, but not for the people who ask but for the people who are willing to answer. After all, bad questions can be dealt with. There are zounds of volunteers who act like a human-powered AI, casting votes being triggered by certain words and phrases in the question.

While it's bad answers which is *the* real plague.

And an exam, similar to the one used to test people who are casting close votes, would really help.

But in time you will realize that no such exam will be implemented on this site of Stack Overflow. Because bad answers are not an unwanted side effect - this is how this site is **designed to work.** Stack Overflow has never been aimed at quality. Every single mechanism, rule, or custom here is aimed towards providing answers, gaining reputation and badges, and enforcing some formal code. But none even touch the subject of quality.

The suggestion you were given in your other question, is Stack Overflow in a nutshell:

> *Vote and move on*

Over the span of all those years, many people tried to shatter this foundation of indifference, all in vain. It didn't even flinch. Surely a Q&A site that will proclaim quality as its goal will bury Stack Overflow in no time. But there is none yet.

Answer (score 4):

**80% - 90% of First posts are full of typos.**

I just did another 900 First post reviews over the last week. There should, at least, be a check for a percentage of typos **especially if every word in the post starts with a capital letter**.

In those cases users should be presented with a large red flashing neon saying:

**You correct the typos or you no post!!!**

A grammar school level exam could be a plus. Do you capitalize the `i` or do you not capitalize the `I`?

Comment: Or, you know, just correct them outright *for* the poster (and let them preview to avoid false positives) :) We, as editors, already have a bunch of tools that are battle-tested - SE could just ask us...

Comment: What action did you take on those 80% - 90%? "Share feedback" does not seem to cover this (though some of them probably have other problems that *are* covered).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I guess I've done around 85% edits overall.

Comment: To give them the benefit of the doubt ([normal meaning of doubt](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429)), they may be used to other platforms where it is not possible to change anything after submit, not even in the first few minutes (e.g., [IRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat), most forums (e.g. [phpBB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpBB)), older versions of Microsoft VSTS (now Azure DevOps), etc.) or where it is too well hidden (e.g., YouTube). They may not even know what "edit" means (unknown concept). -

Comment: cont’ - Though it could just be another symptom of the minimum effort attitude. Or they do it deliberately for some unknown reason (some kind of signalling - to look "smart"?)

Comment: @PeterMortensen whatever the motive, additional system checks on the more common typos would benefit editors/readers downstream.

Answer (score 1):

> Every day, we see hundreds of questions asked that are of such low-quality one might wonder why Stack Overflow even allows to post it. We keep closing and downvoting them, but the problem doesn't end. New users arrive and the ones that get banned just create another account and repost the same question. We need something to stop it.

Yes, everyday low quality questions are asked. It's a bit frustrating, and it is endless.

> I propose that Stack Overflow implements an entrance exam. Every account must go through such an exam before being able to post any questions.

The reality is that such an exam may seem like a good idea but has a lot of downsides.
Firstly, Stack Overflow is a company. They need to make money, and part of that comes from user signups.

It's not even a bad thing: they literally *need* users to signup in order to keep the site running. No user signups = no revenue for Stack Overflow = No site.

Not only that, but if there were less user signups, we wouldn't get *any* new questions, even the good questions that we get. Because 99% of question askers aren't willing to go through a test to ask one question on a site.

If a test (or something similar to this) was presented to a new user, there would be a significant drop in new user signups. Nobody wants to complete even a 5 question test to be able to ask one question on a site. It's just not worth their "precious" time.

Who would want to read through 5 pages of text, and go through a vast FAQ just to ask one question?

I like the idea, but this is likely to never be implemented, and if it were implemented, it's almost like a self destruct button.

Comment: 'Who would want to read through 5 pages of text, and go through a vast FAQ just to ask one question?' - those who don't want their mega-dupes summarily downvoted, closed and deleted?  Those with above-zero consideration for other users?  Those without a demagnetized moral compass?

Comment: ...Those who dump their walls of code and expect us to do the same for them?

Comment: @MartinJames certainly not me to ask one question. Stack exists to help programmers, and it just makes no sense to waste the time of those who want to ask a single question.

Comment: @10Rep oh sure, much better to waste someone else's time:(

Comment: @MartinJames I mean as a volunteer we've just accepted it. I

Comment: @MartinJames plus, to understand from the company's perspective. They literally need user signups. So it's not fair to implement this, right?

Answer (score 1):

> Stop users who are in hurry.

If a person is in a hurry, an exam likely won't change that. It might cause the asker to *further* rush the question writing process with a mind that they already spent too much time on the exam they didn't ask for.

Of course, I'm not saying users asking questions in a hurry causing them to be poorly written are fine, it's just that an exam might make it worse.

Answer (score 0):

It seems inescapable that any such exam would also drive away some people who would otherwise post good questions, be it due to giving up after not getting through the challenge, or to understandably not wanting to spend time studying Stack Overflow arcana in order to pass a test. That suffices to put me off it.

Answer (score 0):

### Do it with a video!

If someone, particularly entry level, wants free help and isn't willing to put the effort into watching a short video that highlights some of the basic expectations then chances are they aren't willing to put the proper effort into a reasonable quality question either.

A short video that shows me how to fix something on my car is a lot more comforting and less time consuming than laboring through a list of instructions and confusing diagrams in a manual.

**The whole help center could be greatly improved with a collection of well produced videos.**

Sure there are issues like language barriers and jumping to the end without watching but they can easily be resolved.

A very simple fun quiz based on the video content where the moderator feeds you the answers should be quite tolerable compared to a dry read-only wall of text

They put *"Some assembly required"* messages on many product packages. SO definitely needs a sign on the door indicating *"Some effort required"*. People are far more apt to absorb that message when spoken to than by reading it.

Comment: With static video content, very soon web sites will come into existence with answers to the quiz(es). Then the barrier will only be the effort required to find and open some other web page, read the answers, etc. (it may deter the minimum-effort users).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Not an insurmountable problem with a bit of creativity.

Comment: As someone who *loathes* videos for things that have no reason to be video-based, this would make me far less likely to contribute.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery That's fair but to each their own. The old `picture = 1000 words` works for many people, particularly when dealing with a  new environment

Comment: @charlietfl Sure, but forcing it on people is a different matter (which is part of why I hate that trend so much, since it's caused a decline in the much-easier-for-me text guides).

Comment: @JohnMontgomery So it could be a choice, read or watch. You might find your preferences are not those of the majority or maybe they are...don't know. Very clear a lot of people do not read around here

Comment: @JohnMontgomery as someone who _loathes_ having to read through a giant wall of text, I would be less likely to contribute. it goes both ways. I think there should be two options.

Comment: @10Rep Now you're asking for twice as much work to implement it. All the more reason why having an "entrance exam" is a bad idea.

Comment: I love the idea of a video explanation. It feels like a far more efficient way to convey information and a lot of people prefer video explainations. Kinda feel like SO should have a youtube channel.